# Apache Lucene com Tika não retornando palavras com acento

Tags: java, lucene

Fiz a implementação da biblioteca [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) e [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) do pacote Apache e consegui fazer ela funcionar super bem para o que eu quero. Porém estou com um problema em palavras com acento, ele não consegue retornar resultados para palavras com acento, acredito que em algum momento os textos estejam sendo salvos com um encoding qualquer que perde esses caracteres. Alguém já passou por essa dificuldade?

**Indexador.java**

```
package br.com.ir;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.br.BrazilianAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class Indexador {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Indexador.class);
    // IndexWriter: cria e mantém o índice;
    private IndexWriter writer;
    // Biblioteca que extrai texto de diversos formatos conhecidos;
    private Tika tika;
    private int qntArq = 0;

    public void iniciaIndexacao() {
        try {
            File diretorio = new File(ArquivoDeConfiguracao.retornaValorIndice());

            apagaIndices(diretorio);

            // Directory: representa o diretório do índice
            Directory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(diretorio);

            // Analyser/StandardAnalyser: fazem o pré-processamento do texto
            // Existem analisadores inclusive em português
            BrazilianAnalyzer analyzer = new BrazilianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);

            // IndexWriterConfig: configurações para criação do índice
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9,
                    analyzer);

            // Inicializa o IndexWriter para gravação
            writer = new IndexWriter(d, config);

            long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(new File(ArquivoDeConfiguracao.retornaValorFonte()));
            // Fecha o IndexWriter e comita as mudanças
            writer.commit();
            long fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    "Quantidade de arquivos indexados: " + qntArq + "\n"
                            + "Tempo para indexar: "
                            + String.valueOf((fim - inicio) / 1000) + "s"
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void apagaIndices(File diretorio) {
        if (diretorio.exists()) {
            File arquivos[] = diretorio.listFiles();
            if (arquivos != null) {
                for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
                    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                    arquivo.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(File raiz) {
        FilenameFilter filtro = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File arquivo, String nome) {
                return nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".odt")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".doc")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docx")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".ppt")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pptx")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith(".rtf")
                        || nome.toLowerCase().endsWith("");
            }
        };

        for (File arquivo : raiz.listFiles(filtro)) {
            if (arquivo.isFile()) {
                try {
                    // Extrai o conteúdo do arquivo com o Tika;
                    String textoExtraido = getTika().parseToString(arquivo);
                    indexaArquivo(arquivo, textoExtraido);
                    qntArq++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                }
            } else {
                indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(arquivo);
            }
        }
    }

    private void indexaArquivo(File arquivo, String textoExtraido) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");

        String ultimaModificacao = formatador.format(arquivo.lastModified());
        // Monta um Document para indexação
        // Field.Store.YES: armazena uma cópia do texto no índice, aumentando
        // muito o seu tamanho
        // Os Fields precisam ser TextField pois senão não irão ser analizados
        // na busca
        Document documento = new Document();
        documento.add(new TextField("UltimaModificacao", ultimaModificacao,
                Field.Store.YES));
        documento.add(new TextField("Caminho", arquivo.getAbsolutePath(),
                Field.Store.YES));
        documento.add(new TextField("Texto", textoExtraido, Field.Store.YES));

        try {
            // Adiciona o Document no índice, mas este só estará disponível para
            // consulta após o commit.
            getWriter().addDocument(documento);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }

    Tika getTika() {
        if (tika == null) {
            tika = new Tika();
        }
        return tika;
    }

    IndexWriter getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme respondido na [versão em inglês do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825662/cant-return-results-for-words-with-accents-on-lucenetika/24831014#24831014) o meu problema estava no Analyzer de consulta, eu estava utilizando o `StandardAnalyzer` ao invés de `BrazilianAnalyzer`, então a query de busca não estava recebendo o devido tratamento quando encontrava os acentos.

**Buscador.java**

```
package br.com.ir;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.br.BrazilianAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

class Buscador {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Buscador.class);
    public int totalDeOcorrencias;
    public String quantBusca;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public Buscador(String parametro, DefaultListModel listModel) {
        try {
            Directory diretorio = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(
                    ArquivoDeConfiguracao.retornaValorIndice()));
            // IndexReader: classe abstrata responsável por acessar
            // o índice;
            IndexReader leitor = DirectoryReader.open(diretorio);
            // IndexSearcher: implementa os métodos necessários para
            // realizar buscas em um índice;
            IndexSearcher buscador = new IndexSearcher(leitor);
            Analyzer analisador = new BrazilianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);
            // QueryParser/Query: representa a consulta do usuário. Outros
            // exemplos de query podem ser vistos no Javadoc;
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_4_9, "Texto",
                    analisador);
            Query consulta = parser.parse(parametro);
            long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Realiza a busca e armazena o resultado em um TopDocs;
            TopDocs resultado = buscador.search(consulta, 100);
            long fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
            totalDeOcorrencias = resultado.totalHits;
            quantBusca = String.valueOf((fim - inicio) / 1000);

            // ScoreDoc: representa cada um dos documentos retornados na busca.
            for (ScoreDoc sd : resultado.scoreDocs) {
                Document documento = buscador.doc(sd.doc);
                // Preenche o modelo
                listModel.addElement(documento.get("Caminho"));
            }
            leitor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```